# TFS Build failure caused by inability to load TFS integration assembly

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm using TFS 2012 (Update 1). I had a build definition setup and working fine, but all of a sudden the build starting failing with the following error:

```
Exception Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.Integration, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) (type FileLoadException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Changeset.get_ArtifactUri()
   at lambda_method(Closure , ActivityContext )
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteInResolutionContextT
   at System.Activities.InArgument`1.TryPopulateValue(LocationEnvironment targetEnvironment, ActivityInstance activityInstance, ActivityExecutor executor)
   at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.InternalTryPopulateArgumentValueOrScheduleExpression(RuntimeArgument argument, Int32 nextArgumentIndex, ActivityExecutor executor, IDictionary`2 argumentValueOverrides, Location resultLocation, Boolean isDynamicUpdate)
   at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.ResolveArguments(ActivityExecutor executor, IDictionary`2 argumentValueOverrides, Location resultLocation, Int32 startIndex)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

The only thing I did between the previous successful build and the failed build was add an installer class to a Windows Service project. Not idea how that would cause this error on the build server.

Other build definitions using the same build process template work fine, and the solution being built builds fine locally. Indeed, it appears this error isn't during the build process itself, but later in the workflow when the **Associate Changesets and Work Items** step executes.

If I disable this in the build definition (Process -> Advanced Section -> Associate Changesets and Work Items), the everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you by chance trying to load a DefaultBuildTemplate.xaml through TFS 2012? Have you tried switching to DefaultBuildTemplate.11.0.xaml ?

Comment: I'm using the 11.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Using an XML editor to remove all strong name references to assemblies is probably the fix here.

(the XML editor within Visual Studio works well - right-click the Build Process Template in question, choose Advanced -> View with... and choose the XML Editor)

Without knowing the full setup however (build agent server OS, Visual Studio version used to open/edit the Build process template, Visual Studio version installed on build agents) I am unfortunately 100% confident.